# django helpdesk -как поменять язык системы

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, как изменить язык системы в django-helpdesk,  у меня получилось изменить язык, просто подменив файлы в locale/en на файлы из ru, но должен же быть и другой способ

Answer (score 1):

в settings.py прописать:
`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'`